# How can I associate data with the location stack in UI-Router

Tags: angularjs

$location forms, effectively, a stack.  You can push URLs on it (by hitting a link), you can pop URLs off it (with the back button).  Unusually, when you pop a URL of the top of the stack, you also put into onto the "next" stack, and with the "forward" button, you can do the reverse.  A link pushes on the location stack and clears the "next" stack entirely.

What I would like to do, within the UI-Router ideally, is associate a small amount of data with the location stack.

The idea is that if the user (for example) opens an accordion, clicks a link, and then clicks back, I can open the accordion to the same place.

Notice that if the domain or path changes, this is done automatically; all of Javascript memory is retained.  With UI-Router, though, only the anchor portion of the URL changes, and I don't know how to simulate this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is associating query params to actions inside your state.

For example: `#/state1url?navOpen=true`, when the nav is opened.

Another way of doing it is listening the $stateChangeStart/$stateChangeSuccess events an create your own stack of visited states and data as a service.

For example:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, fromState, fromParams, toState, toParams) {
    myStackService.addState(fromState.name, {navOpened: $scope.isNavOpened});
  if (myStackService.isBackState(toState.name)) {
     $scope.isNavOpened = myStackService.retrieveStateData(toState.name).navOpened;
  }
});
```

Obviously there is more logic to take into account, but you get the idea.